# Analytical solution to unidimensional transient heat equation with mixed bounday conditions not zero

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, heat-equation, sturm-liouville

I need to solve the equation:

${\partial^2 T(x,t) \over \partial x^2 }= {1 \over \alpha} {\partial T(x,t) \over \partial t}$

With the boundary conditions

$T(0,t)=T_0$ and ${\partial T(L,t) \over \partial x}=-q_L \alpha$

Subject to the initial condition

$T(x,0)=T_i(x)$

I tried to do it by separation of variables and I arrived at a solution but I can not get to propose the general solution

Comment: What is $q(L, t)$? Does $T_i$ have any meaning for its index?

Comment: $q(L,t)$ it's the heat applied in $L$. I've updated the description with the substitution.

Comment: No, $T_i$ it's just a initial temperature function

Comment: Your boundary conditions aren't homogeneous so separation of variables won't work straight off the bat. Make the transformation $$v(x,t) = T(x,t) + \alpha q_{L} x - T_{0}$$ which turns your PDE system into \begin{align} v_{t} &= \alpha v_{xx} \\ v(0,t) &= v_{x}(L,t) = 0 \\ v(x,0) &= T_{i} + \alpha q_{L} x - T_{0} \end{align} which _can_ be solved via separation of variables.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try